# Can't Authenticate Proxy in Node JS

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, authentication, proxy, puppeteer

Nothing too complex with this question, trying to use the [chrome devtools protocol](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) in [chrome remote interface](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface) in order to authenticate with a proxy (headerlessly).

I believe this is already a thing, as the CRI has [AuthChallange](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#type-AuthChallenge) and [AuthChallangeResponse](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#type-AuthChallengeResponse) types, as well as puppeteer (high level API around the devtools protocol) already having an [authenticate method](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/49f25e2412fbe3ac43ebc6913a582718066486cc/src/common/NetworkManager.ts#L106).

From a small amount of previous experience with the chrome remote interface / chrome devtools protocol, I believe that this problem is likely solved by using [Network](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/) events in order to listen out for the "AuthChallange" and send / intercept some kind of response.

This is as much as I am aware of so far, and am looking for that simple piece of code which a day of research and googling has unfortunately not provided.

EDIT:

Checked documentation for devtools protocol, but can't find an event that would be related to connecting to a proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

If anymore information is required I can provide this asap